# Java: Modeling/Rendering an interactive hexagon-shaped graph/chart w/ LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, graph, charts, lwjgl

How do I go about creating a hexagon-shaped graph / chart, viewable on the display window, similar to the one in the middle of this screen-shot?

[image: img]

Clicking on one of the buttons on the outer edge of the chart would increase the corresponding stat, but the stat opposite it would decrease(For example, if someone clicked the 'str' stat until it was at the highest it could be, then the 'int' stat would be at its lowest).

Is there a way to do this in Java using LWJGL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph could be constructed out of solid-colored triangles. The buttons would move the outer points of the triangles in or out.

(If what you want help with is detecting a mouse press on a button or drawing a triangle, you should probably read the LWGL tutorials)